# Google Forms redirection after submission

Tags: html, forms

I'm looking for a solution that when the form is submitted, under the submitted button appears a thank you message appears as oppose to it being redirected to the same web page as i currently have it now.

I'm a novice so please provide an example, thanks.

The relevant bit of script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;"     
onload="if(submitted)          
{window.location='http://originalblueskythinking.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/what-drives-us-    
fantasies-or-dreams_22.html';}"></iframe>
  <form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?     
formkey=dFh5VndEdW9JQzVrUU9FdjYteDNfSHc6MQ&amp;ifq" id="ss-form" method="POST"     
 target="hidden_iframe" 
 onsubmit="submitted=true;">

<br />
<div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-radio">
<div class="ss-form-entry">
<label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0"><b style="font-family: Leelawadee; text-align:    
justify;"><span style="color: orange; font-size: large;">What would you say you are  
more of, a dreamer or fantasist?&nbsp;</span></b></label><br />

<label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0"><b style="font-family: Leelawadee; text-align:  
justify;"><span style="color: orange; font-size: large;"><br /></span></b></label>
<span style="color: white;"><label class="ss-choice-label"><input class="ss-q-radio"   
id="group_0_1" name="entry.0.group" type="radio" value="I'm a dreamer and have a 
ideologist natural" />

</label><span style="font-family: Leelawadee; text-align: justify;">I'm a dreamer and 
have a ideologist natural</span></span><br />

 <span style="color: white; font-size: small;"><input class="ss-q-radio" id="group_0_2"   
 name="entry.0.group" type="radio" value="I'm a fantasist and I find my self escaping " 
 />&nbsp;<span style="font-family: Leelawadee; text-align: justify;">I'm a fantasist 
 and I find my self escaping</span></span><br />
<br /></div>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<input name="pageNumber" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input name="backupCache" type="hidden" value="" />


 <br />
 <div class="ss-item ss-navigate">
 <div class="ss-form-entry">
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
 </div>
 </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  (function() {
  var divs = document.getElementById('ss-form').
  getElementsByTagName('div');
  var numDivs = divs.length;
  for (var j = 0; j < numDivs; j++) {
  if (divs[j].className == 'errorbox-bad') {
  divs[j].lastChild.firstChild.lastChild.focus();
 return;
  }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++) {
  var div = divs[i];
  if (div.className == 'ss-form-entry' &&
   div.firstChild &&
  div.firstChild.className == 'ss-q-title') {
  div.lastChild.focus();
  return;
  }
  }
  })();
  </script></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this will work, however you will most likely need to modify this piece of code here: `if(submitted)

{window.location='http://originalblueskythinking.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/what-drives-us-

fantasies-or-dreams_22.html';}` and then replace it with the necessary Javascript message.

Comment: It i'm a real novice in Java, could you please give me an example?